# How can I sort by weird date format?

Tags: bash, perl, sorting, awk, sed

I have a log file like this:

```
December 20, 2015, 11:00pm
November 18, 2014, 12:00am
October 05, 2012, 11:30pm
October 02, 2012, 5:30pm
October 01, 2012, 12:30am
October 01, 2010, 11:30am
October 01, 2011, 9:30pm
October 01, 2011, 7:30am
...
```

I can use sort for simple date format like this:

```
Mar  4 07:45
Mar  8 06:45
Mar  8 05:45

sort -k1M -k2 -k3 text.txt

Mar  4 07:45
Mar  8 05:45
Mar  8 06:45
```

But I can't use sort for my log file. What can I do for am-pm? How can I do this with `sort` or `awk` or other?

Comment: can you provide a broader case to see all the corners and edges of the problem?

Comment: In your example, the log lines are in exact reverse order (newest on top). If that's always the case, then you can just use `tac` to reverse the order of the lines.

Comment: No no, its just example. Of course not always the case. Thats why I need to sort month, day, year and hour/minute/ - am/pm too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use awk to create a YYYYMMDDHHMM string from each input line and prepend it to each line for output, then pipe that to sort and then cut to remove the string that awk prepended:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="(,? +|:)" }
{
    mthAbbr = substr($1,1,3)
    mthNr = (match("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",mthAbbr)+2)/3
    ampm = $NF; sub(/.*[0-9]/,"",ampm)
    hour = $4 + ( (ampm=="pm") && ($4<12) ? 12 : 0 )
    printf "%04d%02d%02d%02d%02d\t%s\n", $3, mthNr, $2, hour, $5, $0
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file | sort | cut -f2-
October 01, 2010, 11:30am
October 01, 2011, 7:30am
October 01, 2011, 9:30pm
October 01, 2012, 12:30am
October 02, 2012, 5:30pm
October 05, 2012, 11:30pm
November 18, 2014, 12:00am
December 20, 2015, 11:00pm
```

To help you see what's happening, here's the intermediate steps:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
201512202300    December 20, 2015, 11:00pm
201411181200    November 18, 2014, 12:00am
201210052330    October 05, 2012, 11:30pm
201210021730    October 02, 2012, 5:30pm
201210011230    October 01, 2012, 12:30am
201010011130    October 01, 2010, 11:30am
201110012130    October 01, 2011, 9:30pm
201110010730    October 01, 2011, 7:30am

$ awk -f tst.awk file | sort
201010011130    October 01, 2010, 11:30am
201110010730    October 01, 2011, 7:30am
201110012130    October 01, 2011, 9:30pm
201210011230    October 01, 2012, 12:30am
201210021730    October 02, 2012, 5:30pm
201210052330    October 05, 2012, 11:30pm
201411181200    November 18, 2014, 12:00am
201512202300    December 20, 2015, 11:00pm
```

Comment: I tested Ed Morton's `awk`, Fedorqui's `bash`, Glenn Jackman's `perl` solutions, it all works. I accept the Ed Morton's answer, because fastest (for 200k lines). Thank you all!

Answer (score 3):

You can use Bash tools to convert the date to timestamp, prepend this info, sort and remove it back:

```
while IFS=, read -r day year hour; do
   printf "%s %s, %s, %s\n" "$(date -d"$day $year $hour" +"%s")" "$day" "$year" "$hour"
done < file  | sort -n | cut -d' ' -f2-
```

This assumes the format is on the form `day, year, hour`.

#### Step by step

Let's convert the date to timestamp:

```
while IFS=, read -r day year hour;
do
printf "%s %s, %s, %s\n" "$(date -d"$day $year $hour" +"%s")" "$day" "$year" "$hour"
done < a                            
1450648800 December 20,  2015,  11:00pm
1416265200 November 18,  2014,  12:00am
1349472600 October 05,  2012,  11:30pm
1349191800 October 02,  2012,  5:30pm
1349044200 October 01,  2012,  12:30am
1285925400 October 01,  2010,  11:30am
1317497400 October 01,  2011,  9:30pm
```

Let's sort:

```
while IFS=, read -r day year hour;
do
printf "%s %s, %s, %s\n" "$(date -d"$day $year $hour" +"%s")" "$day" "$year" "$hour"
done < a  | sort -n                 
1285925400 October 01,  2010,  11:30am
1317497400 October 01,  2011,  9:30pm
1349044200 October 01,  2012,  12:30am
1349191800 October 02,  2012,  5:30pm
1349472600 October 05,  2012,  11:30pm
1416265200 November 18,  2014,  12:00am
1450648800 December 20,  2015,  11:00pm
```

Let's remove the temporary timestamp:

```
$ while IFS=, read -r day year hour;
do
printf "%s %s, %s, %s\n" "$(date -d"$day $year $hour" +"%s")" "$day" "$year" "$hour"
done < a  | sort -n | cut -d' ' -f2-
October 01,  2010,  11:30am
October 01,  2011,  9:30pm
October 01,  2012,  12:30am
October 02,  2012,  5:30pm
October 05,  2012,  11:30pm
November 18,  2014,  12:00am
December 20,  2015,  11:00pm
```

Answer (score 2):

I remembered I have posted an answer to a similar question. However after searching I cannot find it.

So the idea is calculate the seconds after 1970-01-01, and put as prefix to your original line, then do sort, and finally remove the prefix field.

```
awk -v cmd='date -d"%s" +%s' 
   '{o=$0;gsub(/,/,"");cc=sprintf(cmd,$0,"%s");
     cc|getline d
     close(cc);print d"\x99"o}' file|sort -n|sed 's/.*\x99//'
```

the `\x99` is an invisible char, just to make sure that it won't conflict with existing chars in your file.

The output with your input example:

```
October 01, 2010, 11:30am
October 01, 2011, 7:30am
October 01, 2011, 9:30pm
October 01, 2012, 12:30am
October 02, 2012, 5:30pm
October 05, 2012, 11:30pm
November 18, 2014, 12:00am
December 20, 2015, 11:00pm
```

Answer (score 2):

Another similar approach, using Perl

```
perl -MTime::Piece -lpe '$_ = Time::Piece->strptime($_, "%B %d, %Y, %l:%M%p")->strftime("%s") . "\t" . $_' file | 
sort -n | 
cut -f2-
```

Comment: It's work but first getting error like this: `at /usr/lib/perl/5.18/Time/Piece.pm line 469, <> line 1.`

Comment: Could you not build the sort/cut into the `perl`?

Comment: @Sobrique, certainly, but it would be more verbose, harder to maintain, and most likely slower.

Answer (score 1):

You can still do it field by field by separating composite ones

```
$ sed 's/[ap]m/ &/;s/:/ : /' log \
   | sort -k3,3 -k1,1M -k2,2 -k7 -k4,4n -k6,6 \
   | sed -r 's/ : /:/;s/ ([ap]m)/\1/'

October 01, 2010, 11:30am
October 01, 2011, 7:30am
October 01, 2011, 9:30pm
October 01, 2012, 12:30am
October 02, 2012, 5:30pm
October 05, 2012, 11:30pm
November 18, 2014, 12:00am
December 20, 2015, 11:00pm
```

UPDATE: thanks to Romans not having 0, we have 12 < 1 < 2 < ... for each meridiem (am/pm).  Fix is replacing 12 with 00 and change back after sorting.

```
$ sed 's/[ap]m/ &/;s/12:/00:/;s/:/ : /' log \
    | sort -k3,3 -k1,1M -k2,2 -k7 -k4,4n -k6 \
    | sed -r 's/ : /:/;s/ ([ap]m)/\1/;s/00:/12:/' 

October 01, 2010, 11:30am
October 01, 2011, 7:30am
October 01, 2011, 9:30pm
October 01, 2012, 12:30am
October 02, 2012, 5:30pm
October 05, 2012, 11:30pm
November 18, 2014, 12:00am
November 18, 2015, 12:00am
November 18, 2015, 1:00am
November 18, 2015, 12:00pm
November 18, 2015, 1::00pm
December 20, 2015, 11:00pm
```

ps. Now questioning the chosen format for logs.

Comment: I tested but it's not working. Add `November 18, 2015, 12:00am` and you can test again.

Answer (score 0):

In pure Perl based on [@glennjackman's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34516510/2173773) solution:

```
say $_->[1] for sort {$a->[0] <=> $b->[0]}
map [Time::Piece->strptime($_, "%B %d, %Y, %l:%M%p")->strftime("%s"), $_], @_;
```

assuming array `@_` contains the lines of the log file. This uses the [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform).